# PHP - Get the contents of an post from instagram page using simple php

Tags: php, html, curl, instagram

is there a way to get **instagram page** `the contents of an post` using simple `php`

i did some search and i found this script

```
 $url = 'https://www.instagram.com/pagename/';
 $str = file_get_contents($url);
 $count = 0;
 if(preg_match('#followed_by": {"count": (.*?)}#', $str, $match)) {
    $count = $match[1]; // get the count from Regex pattern
  } 
echo $count;
```

but it is getting only number of follower is there a way
to get  **the contents of an Instagram post** using same concept ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Does "post data" mean HTTP POST data, or the contents of an Instagram post? Whatever the case, this seems a bad way of doing things. There are libraries and API's for interacting with Instagram through web services - Google them.

Comment: i now that there is API's but i wana now if there is an option of doing it like the exemple above

Comment: All you're doing in the example above is reading the entire HTML source of a URL and then searching for a bit of markup to try and extract some content. So the answer is, yes, if you can figure out how to extract the particular bit of content you want. But it's a terrible and unreliable way of doing it - for example if Instagram change their page markup, your application will break. Use a proper library and do things properly, e.g. https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API

Comment: @Andy thanks, i can't say more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i took @Andy advice as he it's not reliable and it's dirty af

So this is what i found to go over the html

> Instagram change their page markup, your application will break.

is this

```
    $username = 'username';
    $instaResult= 
    file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/'.$username.'/media/');
   //decode json string into array

  $data = json_decode($instaResult);

foreach ($data as $posts) {
   foreach($posts as $post){
     $postit = (array) json_decode(json_encode($post), True);
     /* get post text and image */
              echo '<p>' .$postit["caption"]["text"].'</p>';
              echo '<img src="'.$postit["images"]["standard_resolution"]["url"].'" />';
              echo "</br>-----------</br>";
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code that works (today). But as @Andy said, it's not reliable and it's dirty af :)

```
<?php

$source = file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/p/POST_ID/");

preg_match('/<script type="text\/javascript">window\._sharedData =([^;]+);<\/script>/', $source, $matches);

if (!isset($matches[1]))
    return false;

$r = json_decode($matches[1]);

print_r($r);

// Example to get the likes count
// $r->entry_data->PostPage[0]->graphql->shortcode_media->edge_media_preview_like->count
```